# Loop that generates an array of indices by omitting one index at each iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Using a `for` loop, how would I write code to generate an array of indices where at each iteration `k` of the loop, I would generate an array of indices from `[1, 2, 3, ... N]` that excludes `k` from the set?

As an example, if I had `k = 3` iterations, the first iteration would give me indices `(2,3)`, the second iteration would give me indices `(1,3)` and finally the third iteration would give me indices `(1,2)`.

Comment: So what's the pattern exactly?

Comment: You are witnessing the big ones in action! enjoy and learn from all those amazing answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another way for any `n`

```
 n = 3;
 [ii, ~] = find( ~eye(n) );
 indices = reshape( ii, n-1, [] ).'
```

Comment: I'll admit that it is creative, but does it have any advantage over the existing answers. -- Sidenote, I would probably recommend `find(~eye(n))` or `find(1-eye(n))` to save some memory and perhaps gain speed.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin thanks for the comment. I find this solution slightly more readable than [Divakar's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28025810/1714410)

Comment: I think you mean `[ii, ~] = find( ~eye(n) )`

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but is this answer really correct?  I get `[1 1; 2 2; 3 3;]` when I run this code which I don't think is what is expected..?

Comment: I found this one to be more readable than the other solutions (no offence to all other posters).  This is what I would have done. +1.

Answer (score 7):

### Approach #1

You can use **[`setdiff`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)** at each iteration to *exclude* the current iteration ID, like so -

```
for iteration_id = 1:3
    indices = setdiff(1:3,iteration_id)
end
```

Code run -

```
indices =
     2     3
indices =
     1     3
indices =
     1     2
```

---

### Approach #2 (Vectorized)

You can employ a vectorized approach to generate all indices in one go, which could be easily used inside the loop(s) if you have to use those indices -

```
num_iters = 3; %// Number of iterations

all_indices = repmat([1:num_iters]',1,num_iters) %//'
all_indices(1:num_iters+1:end)=[]
valid_indices = reshape(all_indices,num_iters-1,[])'
```

Code run -

```
valid_indices =
     2     3
     1     3
     1     2
```

Comment: I misunderstood question completely. +1 for you

Comment: I've corrected it now. Just a slight variation that avoids `setdiff` and so may be faster

Answer (score 6):

Another very simple way to do this:

```
N=3;
for k=1:N
    [1:k-1,k+1:N]
end
```

Comment: You should perhaps store the indices in an output variable.  What the code is doing is that `ans` gets constantly replaced, and only the indices for the last row get saved.

Comment: @rayryeng This is just the basic building block for making a loop that uses the index. Depending on the loop you may want to store it in a variable, or just use it directly. It is not hard to store the index, but it would cost a little in terms of simplicity.

Comment: Oh of course. Wasn't criticizing the method. In fact it's very readable. I figured that in the spirit of the question, the indices should be stored. Either way I upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
all_indices = [1 2 3]; %// these can be arbitrary numbers, not necessarily 1:N
N = numel(all_indices);
for n = 1:N
    selected_indices = all_indices([1:n-1 n+1:N]);
end
```

---

If you want to generate all at once, as rows of a single matrix, you can use [`nchoosek`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html):

```
all_indices = [1 2 3]; %// again, these can be arbitrary numbers
selected_indices = nchoosek(all_indices, numel(all_indices)-1); %// generate combinations
selected_indices = flipud(selected_indices); %// put results in the intended order
```

In the example, this gives

```
selected_indices =
     2     3
     1     3
     1     2
```

Comment: [Dennis' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28025880/1714410) is very similar and cleaner...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the ordering of the columns, you could simply go with:

```
n = 5;
indices = reshape(ones(n-1,1)*(n:-1:1),n,[]);
```

Not exactly the most self-explanatory one, but it abuses the structure of the matrix `indices`.

```
indices = 5     4     3     2
          5     4     3     1
          5     4     2     1
          5     3     2     1
          4     3     2     1
```

Comment: You can always apply `sort` on a row-basis if one cares about the order :) `indices = sort(indices, 2);`.

Comment: @rayryeng:  `fliplr` would also do the trick. But my goal here was to go as basic as possible: a single matrix multiplication and a `reshape`, which is basically free of cost. ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah!  I didn't realize it was already sorted in reverse order.  Nice :)